# Get any page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I have what I think is a simple question. I know you can create a page that will respond to an AJAX call. Is it possible to just get any page with an AJAX call?

So I mean to say, can I do anything with an AJAX call that I could do with a URL?

EDIT #1

Thanks for all the responses!  Really helped clarify!

Comment: Not really. Ajax does [have some security restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). The remote server has the option to provide permissions. But, no, you can't just request any URL and guarantee success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

AJAX is a powerful mechanism by which you can retrieve and/or load data into the DOM in a flexible manner.  You can do things like grab the content of another page and display all or portions of it on your page.  There is a catch however.

Due to security reasons, you cannot depend on being able to make an AJAX call in a cross-domain manner unless the server on the other domain is properly configured.  This is known as Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).  You can read more about that here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Alternatively, some servers will expose API's that work with JSONP (JSON with Padding), which is a sort of workaround for the Same Origin Policy (SOP) that normally prevents cross-domain requests of this nature.  In JSONP, the remote endpoint in essence wraps the response in a javascript function.  You can read more about JSONP here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 3):

You are limited to requests within the same domain, unlike a normal URL.  There are ways around it using CORS or JSONP in that case.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score -1):

No.

One example is that you can't use AJAX to upload or download files. One workaround for this is to target the upload or download to a hidden iframe and poll that frame for a response. **Update:** it seems some support for this is part of HTML 5 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

A second example is navigating the user to another page. You can load a second page and replace the contents of the window with it, but the URL will still be the original page (the "refresh" and "back" features of the browser will behave accordingly).

A third is cross-domain requests. AJAX calls are limited to the domain the page originated from.

Comment: Ah, yeah, wasn't considering that.  But you could just get any html page, correct?

Comment: As long as it's on the same domain, and as long as you don't mind the browser still believing you're on the original page.

Comment: AFAIK, you can upload files.

Comment: Note: Ajax does now support file uploads with `FormData` and binary downloads with `xhr.responseType` and `xhr.response`, but only with [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) and [compliant browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I might not have been clear. You can certainly make an AJAX request for a file, and get a file response, but as far as I know you can't then save the file to the user's local machine.

Comment: @Jim for example https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/comm_tutorial/upload_ajax.htm